# Accessing a particular column in scala

Tags: list, scala

I have a list of list (of type int) and I need to return the first / second column etc depending on the input given as column index. Any ideas on how to access the item of each row of that particular column? I have attempted it but all I came to is using a map function but I don't know how it works exactly. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

List types can be accessed by index number

```
scala> val a=List(1,3,5,7,11,13);
a: List[Int] = List(1, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13)

scala> a(1)
res0: Int = 3

scala> a(2)
res1: Int = 5
```

Multidimensional Lists work too

```
scala> val a=List(List(1,3,5,7,11,13), List(2,4,6,8,10,12));
a: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13), List(2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12))

scala> a
res2: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13), List(2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12))

scala> a(1)
res3: List[Int] = List(2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12)

scala> a(1)(2)
res4: Int = 6
```

update to answer your comment, function that takes a List of Lists of Ints and a column number

```
scala> val a=List(List(1,3,5,7,11,13), List(2,4,6,8,10,12), List(0,10,20,30,40,50,60));
a: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13), List(2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12), List(0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60))
   scala> def getcol(l: List[List[Int]], n: Int) = (for (i <- l) yield i(n)).toList 
getcol: (l: List[List[Int]], n: Int)List[Int]

scala> getcol(a,0)
res17: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 0)

scala> getcol(a,1)
res18: List[Int] = List(3, 4, 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

One option:

```
def getColumn[T](list: List[List[T]], column: Int): List[T] = {
  list.map(row => row(column))
}
```

Then:

```
scala> val l = List(List(1, 2, 3), List(4, 5, 6), List(7, 8, 9))
l: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1, 2, 3), List(4, 5, 6), List(7, 8, 9))

scala> getColumn(l, 2)
res0: List[Int] = List(3, 6, 9)
```

Comment: The `map` method on List runs a function once for each element of the list and produces a new list, which will contain the results of each function call. The function here is `row => row(column)`, which says "accept a single parameter called `row`, and for each value call its `apply` method with `column` as the parameter" (the code `row(column)` is equivalent to `row.apply(column)`). Since we're working with a list of lists, `row` will be set to each sublist in turn, and `row(column)` is simple list element access -- when `column` is 2 it returns the third element of the list.

Answer (score 0):

```
val nums = List(List(1,2,3),List(4,5,6))
nums map(_(1))  // gives List(2,5)
```

Or in a method with colIndex parameter:

```
def sliceCol[T](ls: List[List[T]], colIndex: Int): List[T] =
  ls map(_(colIndex))

sliceCols(1)  // same result
```

Comment: long-hand is: num map(x => x(index)).  'For each entry in num (a List[Int]), map it to a new val by accessing one of it's elements via index'.     Short hand:  _ introduces a new variable at that point (x) & whacks 'x =>' in front of expression.